# Generating RPG Characters (Objects)

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, interface, role-playing-game

I am a beginner Java programmer. I have just finished up an assignment and would appreciate some advice and/or constructive criticism on my program. I am trying to ensure I do not advance my knowledge using bad practices. For context, I have the assignment details, followed by the full code below:[image]

> **Part 1:** Write an abstract Human class that implements the Human interface above. You’ll need to include the interface in your project.
>
> **Part 2:** Implement the Knight and Wizard classes.
>
> **Part 3:** Write a test program called LastNameWorld, which:
>
> 1. Declares 4 Humans
> 2. Instantiates a Knight
> 3. Instantiates a Wizard and moves it
> 4. Clones the Knight and changes its name
> 5. Checks if the Knight clone is not equal to the original Knight, and if so: *moves the clone*
> 6. Clones the Wizard
> 7. Checks if the Wizard clone is equal to the original Wizard, and if so: *moves the clone*
> 8. Prints the total number of Humans living in this World
> 9. Prints a description (toString) of all Humans to the console
>
> **Part 4:** Add a third Human (e.g. Archer, King, Queen, Paladin, etc) type class to your simulation. This class must contain an equals and a clone method. Add code to your test harness to fully test your new class.

**Main Class**

```
public class BakosWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare 4 humans
        Human[] humans = new Human[4];

        // Create original knight and wizard, then move wizard
        humans[0] = new Knight("Rob", 36, 100, 6.1, 50, 50, "Grey Wind");

        humans[1] = new Wizard("Gandalf", 32, 80, 5.11, 25, 25, 50);
        humans[1].move(45, 45);

        // Creating a new knight, that is a clone of the first knight
        humans[2] = ((Knight) humans[0]).clone();
        // Checks to see if the two knights are NOT equal
        if (((Knight) humans[0]).equals(((Knight) humans[2])) == false) {
            humans[2].move(85, 85);
        }

        // Creating a new wizard, that is a clone of the first wizard
        humans[3] = ((Wizard) humans[1]).clone();
        // Checks to see if the two knights ARE equal
        if (((Wizard) humans[1]).equals(((Wizard) humans[3]))) {
            humans[3].move(60, 60);
        }

        // Print information
        System.out.println("Number of humans: " + Human.getNumHumans());
        for (int i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(humans[i].toString());
        }

        // Creating new human, assassin, the clone, and moving the clone
        Human arya = new Assassin("Arya", 16, 70, 5.9, 20, 20, 80);
        Human aryaClone = ((Assassin) arya).clone();

        if (((Assassin) arya).equals((Assassin) aryaClone)) {
            aryaClone.move(120, 120);
        }

        // Gandalf killed (original) Arya's father, so it's time for her to get her revenge
        ((Assassin) arya).inflictPoison(humans[1]);

        System.out.println("\n\n-UPDATED-\n\n" + arya.toString() + "\n"
                + aryaClone.toString() + "\n" + humans[1].toString());
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface HumanInterface {

    //return the name of the human
    public String getName();

    //change the name of the human
    public void setName(String name);

    //get the age of the human
    public int getAge();

    //change the age of a human
    public void setAge(int a);

    //return the height of the human
    public double getHeight();

    //change the height of a human
    public void setHeight(double h);

    //return the health of a human
    public int getHealth();

    //change the health of a human
    public void setHealth(int h);

    //move a human
    public void move(int x, int y);

    //get Y position of a human
    public int getYPos();

    //get X position of a human
    public int getXPos();

    //return a string representation of a human object
    public String toString();
}
```

**Abstract Class**

```
abstract public class Human implements HumanInterface {

    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected double height;
    protected int health;
    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;

    private static int numHumans;

    public Human(String n, int a, int hea, double hei, int x, int y) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        health = hea;
        height = hei;
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        numHumans++;
    }

    public void move(int x, int y) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }

    public int getXPos() {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getYPos() {
        return yPos;
    }

    public void setHealth(int h) {
        health = h;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        height = h;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setNumHumans(int n) {
        numHumans = n;
    }

    public static int getNumHumans() {
        return numHumans;
    }

    // General toString method
    public String toString() {
        String message;
        if (health <= 0) {
            message = "\n[HUMAN]"
                    + "\n" + name + " is dead.";
        } else {
            message = "xPos: " + xPos
                    + "\nyPos: " + yPos
                    + "\nName: " + name
                    + "\nAge: " + age
                    + "\nHealth: " + health
                    + "\nHeight: " + height;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**Sub-Class: Knight**

```
public class Knight extends Human {

    private String horseName;

    public Knight(String n, int a, int hea, double hei, int xPos, int yPos, String hN) {
        super(n, a, hea, hei, xPos, yPos);
        horseName = hN;
    }

    public void setHorseName(String hN) {
        hN = horseName;
    }

    public String getHorseName() {
        return horseName;
    }

    // Clone the object
    public Knight clone() {
        Knight theClone;
        theClone = new Knight(this.name, this.age, this.health, this.height,
                this.xPos, this.yPos, horseName);
        return theClone;
    }

    // Check to see if 2 objects are the same
    public boolean equals(Knight k) {
        return k.age == this.age
                && k.name.equals(this.name)
                && k.health == this.health
                && k.height == this.height
                && k.xPos == this.xPos
                && k.yPos == this.yPos
                && k.horseName.equals(this.horseName);
    }

    // Knight toString method
    public String toString() {
        String message;
        if (health <= 0) {
            message = "\n[KNIGHT]"
                    + "\n" + name + " is dead.";
        } else {
            message = "\n[KNIGHT]"
                    + "\nxPos: " + xPos
                    + "\nyPos: " + yPos
                    + "\nName: " + name
                    + "\nAge: " + age
                    + "\nHealth: " + health
                    + "\nHorse Name: " + horseName
                    + "\nHeight: " + height;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**Sub-Class: Wizard**

```
public class Wizard extends Human {

    private int magicka;

    public Wizard(String n, int a, int hea, double hei, int x, int y, int m) {
        super(n, a, hea, hei, x, y);
        magicka = m;
    }

    public void castSpell() {

    }

    public void setMagicka(int m) {
        magicka = m;
    }

    public int getMagicka() {
        return magicka;
    }

    // Clone the object
    public Wizard clone() {
        Wizard theClone;
        theClone = new Wizard(this.name, this.age, this.health, this.height,
                this.xPos, this.yPos, magicka);
        return theClone;
    }

    // Check to see if 2 objects are the same
    public boolean equals(Wizard w) {
        return w.age == this.age
                && w.name.equals(this.name)
                && w.health == this.health
                && w.height == this.height
                && w.xPos == this.xPos
                && w.yPos == this.yPos
                && w.magicka == this.magicka;
    }

    // Wizard toString method
    public String toString() {
        String message;
        if (health <= 0) {
            message = "\n[WIZARD]"
                    + "\n" + name + " is dead.";
        } else {
            message = "\n[WIZARD]"
                    + "\nxPos: " + xPos
                    + "\nyPos: " + yPos
                    + "\nName: " + name
                    + "\nAge: " + age
                    + "\nHealth: " + health
                    + "\nMagicka: " + magicka
                    + "\nHeight: " + height;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**Sub-Class: Assassin**

```
public class Assassin extends Human {

    int poison;

    public Assassin(String n, int a, int hea, double hei, int x, int y, int p) {
        super(n, a, hea, hei, x, y);
        poison = p;
    }

    public void inflictPoison(Human h) {
        h.setHealth(0);
        poison = this.poison - 20;
    }

    public void setPoison(int p) {
        poison = p;
    }

    public int getPoison() {
        return poison;
    }

    // Clone the object
    public Assassin clone() {
        Assassin theClone;
        theClone = new Assassin(this.name, this.age, this.health, this.height,
                this.xPos, this.yPos, poison);
        return theClone;
    }

    // Check to see if 2 objects are the same
    public boolean equals(Assassin a) {
        return a.age == this.age
                && a.name.equals(this.name)
                && a.health == this.health
                && a.height == this.height
                && a.xPos == this.xPos
                && a.yPos == this.yPos
                && a.poison == this.poison;
    }

    // Assassin toString method
    public String toString() {
        String message;
        if (health <= 0) {
            message = "\n[ASSASSIN]"
                    + "\n" + name + " is dead.";
        } else {
            message = "\n[ASSASSIN]"
                    + "\nxPos: " + xPos
                    + "\nyPos: " + yPos
                    + "\nName: " + name
                    + "\nAge: " + age
                    + "\nHealth: " + health
                    + "\nPoison: " + poison
                    + "\nHeight: " + height;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite well structured. A few points:

## Useless cast before calling a method

These cast bother me:

> ```
> // Creating a new knight, that is a clone of the first knight
> humans[2] = ((Knight) humans[0]).clone();
> // Checks to see if the two knights ARE equal
> if (((Wizard) humans[1]).equals(((Wizard) humans[3]))) { //...
> ```

The clone method will clone the object. Whatever their type, they'll be cloned to the *same* class, be it `Wizard`, `Assassin`, or whatever. But you don't need to know their *exact* type to compare them using `equals`, because that method conveniently only requires the compared object to be `Object`.

So this does the same thing:

```
 // Creating a new knight, that is a clone of the first knight
humans[2] = humans[0].clone();
// Checks to see if the two knights ARE equal
if (humans[1]).equals(humans[3])) { //...
```

But for that to work, you'd need to have a proper `equals` and a proper `clone` methods...

## `Clonable` interface

From the [Java API documentation on clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()):

> [...] if the class of this object does not implement the interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown.

So you need to decide who should carry out this function (the `Human` interface, the Abstract class or whatnot) and make it extend/implement `cloneable`.

## Implement `equals` properly

Your *declaration* of `equals` is unorthodox, and probably does not do what you're thinking  You are probably expected to `Override` the `Object.equals(Object obj)` method. Right now, your Human objects cannot compare theselves. Only `Assassin` with `Assassin`, `Wizard` with `Wizard`, etc. but **not** `Assassin` versus `Wizard`.

So when you call `assassin.equals(otherAssassin)`, you're calling your own function `Assassin.equals`. But when calling `human.equals(otherHuman)` you're calling the `Object.equals(Object)`, and it might not suit you perfectly because your did not override it. This is the reason you needed to cast earlier... now you won't!

I propose that you shed a lot of boilerplate by centralizing the tedious parts of the usual equals implementation (type checking, null checking etc.), by using [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) :

```
public abstract class Human implements HumanInterface {
    [...blah blah blah]
    public boolean equals(Object 
        if (other != null && other instanceof Human) {
            Human otherHuman = (Point) obj;
            return otherHuman.equals(this); // Order is important!
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // I like to provide default implementation, but at least one MUST be overriden
    public boolean equals(Knight knight){ return false; }
    public boolean equals(Wizard wizard){ return false; }
    public boolean equals(Assassin assassin){ return false; }

}
```

And then each concrete class only has to override their corresponding method:

```
public class Knight extends Human {
    [...blah blah blah...]
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Knight knight){
         [...your own implmentation here...]
    }
}
```

---

You see, `toString`, `clone`, `equals` and `hashCode` are methods of `Object`, so absolutely ALL classes **must** abide by the contract defined by the `Object` class. And you still have that last one to code...

This also means the `public String toString();` declaration in `HumanInterface`  is useless.

## String handling

> ```
> message = "\n[ASSASSIN]"
>                 + "\nxPos: " + xPos
>                 + "\nyPos: " + yPos
>                 + "\nName: " + name
>                 + "\nAge: " + age
>                 + "\nHealth: " + health
>                 + "\nPoison: " + poison
>                 + "\nHeight: " + height;
> ```

Please use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) when concatenating many `Strings`, or (better here) a [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to make this safe and more efficient.

## Comment clutter

> ```
> // Assassin toString method
> public String toString() {
> ```

And

> ```
> // Check to see if 2 objects are the same
> public boolean equals(Assassin a) {
> ```

These comment brings nothing, remove it, or turn it into a proper Javadoc. For `toString`, its probably useless.

But `inflictPoison(Human h)` would need some. Especially since it can make `poison` go negative... and still work.

## Storing the humans

Why use an `Array`, and not a `List`? you create and kill humans, it would make sense. You would then also be able to `remove()` them when dead.

Then counting them would be as simple as `list.size();`

Moreover, I would rather keep an individual (correctly typed) reference to each of them, s that their special skills are available without casting!

This would read way better:

```
 // Create original knight and wizard, then move wizard
 Knight rob = new Knight("Rob", 36, 100, 6.1, 50, 50, "Grey Wind");
 Wizard gandalf = new Wizard("Gandalf", 32, 80, 5.11, 25, 25, 50);
 rob.move(45, 45);

 // Creating a new knight, that is a clone of the first knight
 Knight robClone = rob.clone();
 // Checks to see if the two knights are NOT equal
 if (!rob.equals(robclone)) {
     robclone.move(85, 85);
 }

 // Creating a new wizard, that is a clone of the first wizard
 Wizard gandalfClone = gandalf.clone();
 // Checks to see if the two wizards ARE equal
 if (gandalf.equals(gandalfClone)) {
     gandalfClone.move(60, 60);
 }

 // [...]

 // Creating new human, assassin, the clone, and moving the clone
 Assassin arya = new Assassin("Arya", 16, 70, 5.9, 20, 20, 80);
 Human aryaClone = arya.clone();

 if (arya.equals(aryaClone)) {
     aryaClone.move(120, 120);
 }

 // Gandalf killed (original) Arya's father, so it's time for her to get her revenge
 arya.inflictPoison(gandalf);

 System.out.println("\n\n-UPDATED-\n\n" + arya.toString() + "\n"
            + aryaClone.toString() + "\n" + gandalf.toString());
```

## Take advantage of your `BakosWorld` class

Make it a useful object, let it hold the list! Then instantiate a `World` in your main, and start `world.killEachOther()`!

In general, a main method should **only** be an entry point, so should look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeObject business = new SomeObject(args); // instantiate somehow
    business.start(); // Everything happens here, so it is reusable!
}
```

## Naming

CamelCase and such are good.

However  some names must be made more explicit. I can't understand:

```
    public Knight(String n, int a, int hea, double hei, int xPos, int yPos, String hN) {
```

Especially... without comments/Javadoc! This was the one place some would have been useful.

---

That's it for now! Happy coding